# How do I navigate to the popular videos on YouTube when I'm logged in

Tags: youtube

When I'm logged out of YouTube, I can easily navigate to the popular videos because there is a link on the homepage:

[image: YouTube popular]

However, when I'm logged in, this link disappears. All I can see is my subscriptions:

[image: YouTube logged in]

I would like to be able to navigate to both my subscriptions and also popular videos without having to log in and out back and forth. I know you can find the popular videos by clicking "browse channels", but that won't list all the popular videos. It just automatically plays a random popular video with no list to scroll through.

I also tried to subscribe to the popular channel, but it never appeared on my homepage feed. I couldn't locate it when filtering my subscriptions with the word "popular".

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to see a button called as **Trending** on the left side below the subscription menu.

In the **new interface** the Trending button is hidden and the way to get to it is by going here

1. http://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard
2. http://www.youtube.com/charts/videos_views?t=w

Hope this helps!

Comment: I do not see it. My last buttons on the left are "Browse channels" and "Manage subscriptions".

Comment: Mine and your's youtube interface is completely different .The youtube i get has a dark grey colored theme,which is packed with options like history,subscriptions,suggested channels etc .

Answer (score 0):

Click on the 'Browse Channels' thingy there should be another thingy right there that says 'Popular on YouTube'. Yep.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can see the trending videos on YouTube:

Go to the YouTube homepage. Below the list of pages you subscribe to, are two options:

1. browse channels
2. manage subscription

Then go to browse channels, under the popular on YouTube box.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally found out where the popular page link is!

1. On the home page there is that column on the left, where all of your channels that you have subscribe to are.
2. Scroll down to the very bottom of your subscriptions.
3. There should be a link to the popular page at the bottom.

Comment: Adding a few screenshots would make your answer even better !!